# If A = 1 and B = 1 what is the output of the logic circuit below?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, circuit-analysis

[image]

I have labelled the transistors **Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X**.

Suppose **A = 1, B = 1**.

**Q** will be **open**.

**R** will be **closed**.

**S** will be **open**.

**W** will be **closed**.

I am not sure about **T**. Since **S** is open, that means **T** recieves a **0** input, and since it is a not-transistor, is will instead be **closed?** From **W's** input, I think **U** is **open**, and **V** is closed. Then there is not a direct path from **Vcc** to **X** output, so I think the output is **0**. Is this correct?

Comment: It seems S will be closed, because R will put it's gate to 0V, closing it.

Comment: If S is not conducting then the state of T is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

Forget the A input, if B=1 the X-labeled transistor becomes a pull-down, which forces a 0 at U and V. U then pulls-up, and your output becomes **1**.

For illustration, consider the same schematic with the transistors replaced by switches. You can see that, when B=1, the A input doesn't come into play.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- transistors Q, R form a NOT gate for signal A.
- transistors S, T, W, X form a NOR gate whit inputs ~A and B.
- transistors U, V form a NOT gate for the output of the NOR gate.

So all together it forms an OR gate with inputs ~A and B,
i.e. X = ~A ⊕ B
therefore if A=1 and B=1 output will be 1.

Answer (score 3):

If you're used to reading schematics, the fastest solution is looking at what signal B does to transistor X:

- Signal B=1 turns on transistor X. Therefore, ...
- the input to transistors U and V will be 0 ("low"), and...
- U and V invert this zero, ...
- making signal X (output) a "high".

If you like a more formal method and want to get a description of the entire circuit for any configuration of your input signals A and B, you can identify the individual logic blocks in the circuit:

[image]

- Transistors Q and R are an inverter for signal A.
- Transistors S, T, W and X are a NOR gate for signals NOT(A) and B.
- Transistors U and V are another inverter and turn the NOR gate into an OR gate. Therefore, the output is X = NOT(A) OR B.

[image]

*Note: A nice rule to remember: Build a NOR by paralleling N-channel FETs and connecting P-channel FETs in series. Build a NAND by connecting N-channel FETs in series and paralleling P-channel FETs. This, and some Boolean equations, are the key to "anything CMOS".*

Answer (score 2):

As for your main question concerning the outputs state, Blair's answer tells you all you need.

As for your assumptions, I think you made some mistakes there:

- Since **R** is **closed**, **S** and **W** will have **0** at the
  input. So **S** will be **closed** and **W** will be **open**.
- The input of **T** has nothing to do with the state of **S**. Instead
  it directly receives the circuit input **B**.

Comment: Why do you say that W has a 0 at the input? If R is closed, and the A provides a 1 input, how does the input reaching W become a 0?

Comment: @KSplitX in this case, think of a mechanical switch. The button (gate) of the switch makes or breaks the connection between the source and drain, so that the signal on the source (or drain) can pass through. The signal on the gate (your hand, for a mech. switch) doesn't pass through, it just makes the connection.